# Extension of protocol with method which adds default parameter

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I'm used to having default parameters inside protocols using extensions, as protocol declarations themselves can't have them, like this:

```
protocol Controller {
   func fetch(forPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?)
}

extension Controller {
   func fetch(forPredicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) {
      return fetch(forPredicate: nil)
   }
}
```

Worked perfectly for me.

Now I have the next situation, I have one specific protocol for specific kind of controller:

```
protocol SomeSpecificDatabaseControllerProtocol {
    //...
    func count(forPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?) -> Int
}
```

And protocol-extension with implementations of default methods for controllers:

```
protocol DatabaseControllerProtocol {
    associatedtype Entity: NSManagedObject
    func defaultFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity>
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext { get }
}

extension DatabaseControllerProtocol {
    func save() {
        ...
    }

    func get() -> [Entity] {
        ...
    }

    func count(forPredicate predicate: NSPredicate?) -> Int {
        ...
    }

    //.....
}
```

My issue is when I'm trying to add method with default parameter to the `SomeSpecificDatabaseControllerProtocol` extension, I'm receiving a compile-time error, that concrete class conforming to `SomeSpecificDatabaseControllerProtocol` doesn't conform to the protocol (happens only if I extend protocol):

```
class SomeClassDatabaseController: SomeSpecificDatabaseControllerProtocol, DatabaseControllerProtocol {...}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is happening because compiler is confuse due to ambiguous functions.**

> 1. Here `SomeClassDatabaseController` receiving `count()` method from two different protocols.
> 2. `DatabaseControllerProtocol` has `count(forPredicate)` method which always need parameter.
> 3. On other hand `SomeSpecificDatabaseControllerProtocol` have `count()` method which can have empty parameter.
> 4. To solve this either you have to change count method in `DatabaseControllerProtocol` to this or you have to implement it in `SomeClassDatabaseController`.
>
> `func count(forPredicate predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> Int { return 0}`

Comment: yes, exactly, that was what I've just understood :) 
the most painless way is to change the interface of func with `DatabaseControllerProtocol` declaration

Comment: Sometimes we need to be more specific. We cannot always rely on tools. Or there has to be away to specify which class method it should call.